# phpdocx replace template header variable using wordfragment not working

Tags: php, phpdocx

i am using phpdocx to genarate word document.

i have dynamically changed  headers in words.
 so i want to replace header variable dnamically.
phpdocx forum they say it can be done using  WordFragment method  but it not work..
 http://www.zxcv.phpdocx.com/en/forum/default/topic/734

here is my code i put  $TESTTT$  variable in header

```
//path to  the CreateDocx class within your PHPDocX installation
require_once '../../../classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$docx = new CreateDocxFromTemplate('Doc.docx');

//create the Word fragment that is going to replace the variable
$wf = new WordFragment($docx, 'document');
$text='try to add head';

$wf->addText($text);

$docx->replaceVariableByWordFragment(array('TESTTT' => $wf), array('type' => 'block'));


$docx->createDocx('tessst');
```

Comment: You should ask in phpdocx forum

Comment: i also done.i want to quickly fix this

Answer (score 0):

when creating from template you also need to add:

require_once '../../../classes/CreateDocxFromTemplate.inc';

Comment: i found error There is an error in the online API docs as you can check from the class headers and footers are not suported :-(

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use a Word fragment?

With PHPDocx you may easily replace text variables and placeholder images and that should be enough most of the time.

If it is not the case you may use the import headers and footers method or replace the whole thing with the add header method.

Answer (score 0):

Currently phpdocx do not support changing variables by wordfragment either the header or footer.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working with me

```
$docx = new CreateDocxFromTemplate('docTemplate/HeaderTest.docx');
$docx->setTemplateSymbol('#');
$variables = array('VAR_NAME' => "SOME TEXT");
$options = array('target' => 'header');
$docx->replaceVariableByText($variables, $options);
```